# Postgresql select query with ascii value in WHERE clause

Tags: postgresql

I want to filter a field with a ascii key's value in postgres.

I have a field called location and it's rows data contains '/'. I want to write my query and get all the rows with '/' in its content. Here I just want to pass the ascii code for the '/' instead of '/' itself. I am very new to PostgreSQL and don't know how to achieve the requirement. Please find below query I am trying to execute for the desired result and suggest with the changes.

```
SELECT * FROM my_test_table WHERE (location LIKE '%' || convert_to('&#47;', 'UTF8') || '%');
```

Expected Result: When I execute the above query, I should get all the rows which contain '/' in its content.

Thanks in advance
Santosh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`chr()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html) function:

```
SELECT * 
FROM my_test_table 
WHERE location like '%'||chr(47)||'%'
```

or alternatively using `strpos()` instead of like

```
SELECT * 
FROM my_test_table 
WHERE strpos(location, chr(47)) > 0;
```